# How to obtain the value of a property using the Environment API in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a specific requirement to obtain the value of a property using the `Environment API` without field/constructor injection. Since I am using a private method, injecting a property with the `@Value` annotation is also not working without a class variable.

This is the private method signature.

```
public int getCustomProperty(String key) {
    Environment env;
    ...// I'm not able to find out an example code
    return env.getProperty(key, Integer.class);
}
```

Comment: You need to inject the `Environment` else it will simply no work. So either the requirements aren't as you state they are, or is given by people who have no clue how Spring (Boot) works.

Comment: The requirement was not to define new class variables. Anyway it's working with the following code snippet, but I'm not sure is that the correct approach. `var appContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder().web(WebApplicationType.NONE).sources(Application.class).run();` and `var env = appContext.getEnvironment();`

Comment: It depends on where that code is... If that is in the place you need the environment you are doing it wrong and you should stop using that, as it will load all your beans again in a new application context. Basically duplicating everything, which is **not** what you want.